# Altering EF Core Schema (onDelete) not working, constriant issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, .net-core

I have a DB migration that I created many migrations ago that I'm now running into problems with (schema was not correct).

The original migration created a SeriesRelation, which allows a Series to be linked to another Series (that is not itself) with some extra metadata. The goal was when I removed any series in the relationship, the underlying Series wouldn't delete. However, because of this oversight, I ended up not being able to delete any Series with a SeriesRelation as a FK constraint is being thrown, with a lack of Cascade.

To address this, I want to change the `FK_SeriesRelation_Series_SeriesId` to Cascade deletion so that a Series can delete the SeriesRelation row when deleted, but any relation being removed wont delete the source Series rows.

I have tried with a custom migration, but it doesn't take (checked via Rider's Database tool). Any ideas?

**Custom Migration**

```
migrationBuilder.DropForeignKey(
                name: "FK_SeriesRelation_Series_SeriesId",
                table: "SeriesRelation");
            migrationBuilder.AddForeignKey(
                name: "FK_SeriesRelation_Series_SeriesId",
                table: "SeriesRelation",
                column: "SeriesId",
                principalTable: "Series",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
```

**Original Migration**

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "SeriesRelation",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    Id = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("Sqlite:Autoincrement", true),
                    RelationKind = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                    TargetSeriesId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false),
                    SeriesId = table.Column<int>(type: "INTEGER", nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_SeriesRelation", x => x.Id);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_SeriesRelation_Series_SeriesId",
                        column: x => x.SeriesId,
                        principalTable: "Series",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Restrict);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_SeriesRelation_Series_TargetSeriesId",
                        column: x => x.TargetSeriesId,
                        principalTable: "Series",
                        principalColumn: "Id",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_SeriesRelation_SeriesId",
                table: "SeriesRelation",
                column: "SeriesId");

            migrationBuilder.CreateIndex(
                name: "IX_SeriesRelation_TargetSeriesId",
                table: "SeriesRelation",
                column: "TargetSeriesId");

builder.Entity<SeriesRelation>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Series)
                .WithMany(p => p.Relations)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.SeriesId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

            builder.Entity<SeriesRelation>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.TargetSeries)
                .WithMany(t => t.RelationOf)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TargetSeriesId);
```

In case it's relevant, the classes in question can be found here:

Series: [https://github.com/Kareadita/Kavita/blob/develop/API/Entities/Series.cs](https://github.com/Kareadita/Kavita/blob/develop/API/Data/Migrations/20220421214448_SeriesRelations.cs)

Original Migration: https://github.com/Kareadita/Kavita/blob/develop/API/Data/Migrations/20220421214448_SeriesRelations.cs

Edit: Fluent API:

```
builder.Entity<SeriesRelation>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Series)
            .WithMany(p => p.Relations)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.SeriesId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

        builder.Entity<SeriesRelation>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.TargetSeries)
            .WithMany(t => t.RelationOf)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TargetSeriesId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade); // I added this OnDelete, but it doesn't work
```

Comment: Did you generate a new migration after the changes? If yes did you got any error ?!

Comment: I generated a blank migration and copied the Custom migration code in and ran my code, which applies migrations at startup. I used a debugger as well to validate it ran the code, but after inspecting the DB with Rider's database tool, the scheme still showed the lack of cascade on delete, while the other FK had it (which was setup in the original migration)

Comment: You should have done the necessary changes and let the EF generate the code it self when generating the migrations. I use always Code first, Models simple as possible then all the stuff needed with the FluentAPI. Don't know what are you using, but if you where using the FluentAPI it would just add the `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` call to the FK configuration. But if I remenber right, the default behavior is Cascade

Comment: Yeah, I def changed it afterwards to ClientCasade as I had a bad understanding. I tried with FluentAPI, with this:
`builder.Entity<SeriesRelation>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.Series)
                .WithMany(p => p.Relations)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.SeriesId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

            builder.Entity<SeriesRelation>()
                .HasOne(pt => pt.TargetSeries)
                .WithMany(t => t.RelationOf)
                .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TargetSeriesId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);`

Comment: Do I need to use FluentAPI on my Series entity or on the SeriesRelation? Because the constraint is thrown when I'm deleting my Series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I solved this, but not with EF. What I did was included in the JOIN to pull back the Relation, so when I performed the delete, the cascades took effect:

```
return await _context.Series
        .Include(s => s.Volumes)
        .Include(s => s.Metadata)
        .ThenInclude(m => m.CollectionTags)
        .Include(s => s.Relations)
        .Where(s => seriesIds.Contains(s.Id))
        .AsSplitQuery()
        .ToListAsync();
```

I also put this in my DataContext:

```
builder.Entity<SeriesRelation>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.Series)
            .WithMany(p => p.Relations)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.SeriesId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);

        builder.Entity<SeriesRelation>()
            .HasOne(pt => pt.TargetSeries)
            .WithMany(t => t.RelationOf)
            .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.TargetSeriesId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade);
```

This ended up solving it for me. Thank you to those who commented and helped me find the end solution.